# How do I scrolling through multitail output when using command line filters?

Tags: multitail

I'm currently filtering out unwanted lines when using multitail

```
$ multitail -ev "foo|bar" -kr 0 55 -f /var/log/syslog
```

The problem is, when I want to scroll back through the output, the only way I know of how to do this is using the b command. The problem is, b brings up a buffer window that has all of the original (unfiltered) lines in it. How do I scroll through the output without seeing the lines that I don't care about?